# limit certain number of clients to connect to server

Tags: java, sockets

I've made a chat application which has a server and clients.
i want to limit the connection of clients to a certain number, lets say 2.
i've tried to do that by defining my ServerSocket as somevar = new ServerSocket(port,2).
the issue is when a client disconnects a new client can't still login (after reaching the limit of 2 connections), it seems like the closed sockets is counted as a connected sockets.
anyone got an idea to solve this issue?

Comment: can you paste some code to show us what cleanup action you are performing when the client sends a disconnect request ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep a track of all the clients connected in an array

```
Client[] clients=new Clients[4];
```

Now when a client disconnects you have to make that Client space on the array null and before that close any open streams for that user. Making a space null in array will open it for new clients.

Comment: I think ServerSocket(port, clientQueueSize) takes care of this, and we do not need bolier plate code to manage incoming clients.

Comment: well that is the main reason I'm suggesting to keep track of the Clients and  do manual cleaning... Cause as it turns out using a queue doesn't clean up the space on the queue when a client disconnects ...

Comment: @Kakarot You are mistaken. The `clientQueueSize` defines the maximum number of connections which have been completed but not accepted yet. It is called the 'backlog'. Nothing to do with the number of concurrently connected clients.

Answer (score 1):

> I've made a chat application which has a server and clients.
>   i want to limit the connection of clients to a certain number, lets say 2.
>   i've tried to do that by defining my ServerSocket as somevar = new ServerSocket(port,2).

That's not what that parameter is for. It doesn't define the mximum number of connected clients. It defines the maximum size of the listen backlog queue, which is the number of pending connection connections that haven't been accepted yet.

> the issue is when a client disconnects a new client can't still login (after reaching the limit of 2 connections)

That's not correct.

> it seems like the closed sockets is counted as a connected sockets.
>   anyone got an idea to solve this issue?

Just count. Increment a counter when you accept, and decrement when you close that connection.